# pandas way to get list of indexes using iloc?

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have data sorted the way I want.
I'm about to put in something like:

```
series_data = []
for count,x in enumerate(df):
   series_data.append(list(range(count)))
   df['up_to_row'].iloc(count)= series_data
```

so the column would be:

```
df['up_to_row'] = Series([0], [0,1], [0,1,2], [0,1,2,3]...)
```

Then I need to translate this iloc locations to indexes.

Is there a more pandas specific way to do this?
I would do this with pandas operators but I'm not sure how to get the current iloc (which is why the enumerate was needed)

Edit*
Found the final answer using some of the tools from @wen.  Thank you.

```
data['ind']=data.index.astype(str)+','
data['cumsum_indexes']=data['ind'].cumsum().str[:-1].str.split(',')
```

Comment: Can you do `series_data.append(df.index[list(range(count))])` to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cumsum` , Notice it will convert number in list to str , not int anymore.

```
df['up_to_row']=np.arange(len(df))
(df['up_to_row'].astype(str)+',').cumsum().str[:-1].str.split(',')
Out[211]: 
0             [0]
1          [0, 1]
2       [0, 1, 2]
3    [0, 1, 2, 3]
Name: up_to_row, dtype: object
```

Comment: I like the str+','.  How do you convert those iloc's to the indexes they represent?